# Possibility to ignore application path in language cookie

Tags: cookies, aspnetboilerplate

I need to generate the language cookie "Abp.Localization.CultureName" ignoring the application path.

I found in the source code this part:

```
    protected virtual void SetCultureToCookie(HttpContext context, string culture)
    {
        context.Response.SetCookie(
            new HttpCookie(_webLocalizationConfiguration.CookieName, culture)
            {
                Expires = Clock.Now.AddYears(2),
                Path = context.Request.ApplicationPath
            }
        );
    }
```

How can I override this?

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subclass `CurrentCultureSetter` to override:

```
public class MyCurrentCultureSetter : CurrentCultureSetter
{
    protected override void SetCultureToCookie(HttpContext context, string culture)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

And replace the service in your module's `PreInitialize()` method:

```
Configuration.ReplaceService<ICurrentCultureSetter, MyCurrentCultureSetter>();
```

Comment: Thx aaron, I have created my custom class and partially works.
Looking through the code I find the class AbpLocalizationController with the following code:

public virtual ActionResult ChangeCulture ...
...
            Response.Cookies.Add(
                new HttpCookie(_webLocalizationConfiguration.CookieName, cultureName)
                {
                    Expires = Clock.Now.AddYears(2),
                    Path = Request.ApplicationPath
                }
            );

Why this? I think is redundant, anyway I also will override this

Comment: That is used here: https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-core-template/search?q=ChangeCulture

Comment: Yes I know that is used in the base MVC controller for localization, my real question is about duplication, why the cookie creation is in two places? Is it not better to centralize the creation of the cookie inside the CurrentCultureSetter class? Also because the module Abp.Web.Mvc depends on the module Abp.Web

Comment: Application uses `ICurrentCultureSetter`; user uses `AbpLocalizationController`.